# Magento Static Blocks not showing after site migration

Tags: magento, static-block

I just migrated a website from LIVE to my Local system. After migration, the site seems to be working fine however the static blocks are not appearing anywhere on the website. They do exists in admin section, I also tried adding new static blocks but they as well doesn't showed up.
I used the following code to call them on frontend

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('brand-banners')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not have static block with the identifier brand-banners create it under admin->cms->static blocks select store and set status to enable

Comment: I do have it in backend, in fact any of the static block is not showing up!

Comment: clear the cache and reindexing data if you have still face the problem share screen shot